# File system error in ms flow from powerapps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

When create file system in ms flow using power apps its getting error like

> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_file' inputs at line '1' and column '2179': 'The template language expression 'json(decodeBase64(triggerOutputs().headers['X-MS-APIM-Tokens']))['$connections']['shared_filesystem']['connectionId']' 
>   cannot be evaluated because property 'shared_filesystem' doesn't exist, available properties are ''. 
>   Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Test` then `Use tests from previous runs`? Try using `I'll perform the trigger action` instead.

I've seen the error you mentioned after you add an action which requires a new Connection, but try to use previous test runs that *do not* have the Connection established.

(If that makes sense)

Comment: Same case for me. I fixed after executing the trigger. I'll avoid using *Use test from previous runs* in these scenarios.